# django 1.11.x -> 2.x migration. I got the incorrect 'group by' fields

Tags: python, django

I just upgraded the Django version. The model or code has not been modified in my app.

But... I get different results QuerySet.

Fields specified in 'Group by' are different when printing a 'query'.

Model:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    id_field = models.AutoField(db_column='id_', primary_key=True)
    ...
    collections = models.ManyToManyField('Collection',
                        through='CollectionMap', 
                        through_fields=('contentid', 'collectionid'))

class CollectionMap(models.Model):
    field_index = models.AutoField(db_column='_index', primary_key=True)
    collectionid = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='collectionid')
    contentid = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='contentid')
    field_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_time')

class Collection(models.Model):
    field_index = models.AutoField(db_column='_index', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    collectionorder = models.IntegerField(db_column='collectionOrder', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    field_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='_time')
```

Code:

```
Content.objects\
        .annotate(count=Count('id_field')\
        .values('id_field', 'collections__name')
```

Query:

1.11.X

```
SELECT
    Content.id_, Collection. name 
FROM Content
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Collection_Map ON (Content.id_ = Collection_Map.contentid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Collection ON (Collection_Map.collectionid = Collection._index)
GROUP BY Content.id_
ORDER BY Content.itemOrder DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

2.X

```
SELECT
    Content.id_, Collection. name 
FROM Content
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Collection_Map ON (Content.id_ = Collection_Map.contentid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Collection ON (Collection_Map.collectionid = Collection._index)
GROUP BY Content.id_, Collection. name 
ORDER BY Content.itemOrder DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Group By fields:

> Version 1.11.X : GROUP BY `Content`.`id`
>   Version 2.X : GROUP BY `Content`.`id`, `Collection`.`Name`

I want this... '... GROUP BY Content.id ...'

What should I do??

Comment: Can you print the full query here? Also, what does `GROUP BY` on an `AutoField` achieve?

Comment: @rtindru The 'collection' has a different 'name' but id_field is the same content. I want to have only one 'id field', 'name' by 'GROUP BY' the duplicate 'id field'.

Comment: Can you add the code for the collection model?

Comment: @rtindru I added a collection model.

Comment: I'm confused how the 1.11 group by could even work. As your code reads, a content can have multiple collections, and each of these collection can have a different name. So it makes plenty sense to group by / aggregate on the collection name field. Since there isn't much to aggregate on a varchar, group by makes sense to me. What am I missing?

Comment: No, you're right. I also don't understand how the Django 1.11 'GROUP BY' could even worked. T^T Thanks your answer.